# Image C# file info

Tags: c#, winforms, image

I have an app that captures image from webcam,I convert it to bitmap, now i want its info being read.

```
System.IO.FileInfo obj = new System.IO.FileInfo(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Photo0250.jpg");
```

Instead of passing the path to file, I want to pass the bitmap i have.

Any ideas?

Or do I have to first save it to hard disk and the read it again? :(

Comment: What info are you interested in?

Comment: `FileInfo` is for files, bitmaps are just bytes arranged in a specific pattern and have nothing to do with files until they are saved. What kind of info are you trying to get out of it?

Comment: `FileInfo` returns information about the file from the point of view of the filesystem, e.g. creation time, modification time, etc.  If you have an unsaved bitmap object there is no filesystem information to query.  What do you actually want to know about the bitmap?

Comment: Yes i know that @ChrisHaas, I actually need this object for photosharing function of facebook c# sdk. any ideas?

Comment: @arx Thanks I got your point,:) its not possible... I wanted to read the image share it on facebook via winform aap by skiping the saving it to disk step.

Comment: If you absolutely need a `FileInfo` object then you need to persist it do disk first. None of the methods or properties make sense until you do.

Comment: Thanks everyone and ill do that @ChrisHaas...Thanks

Comment: With reference to your reply to @arx's comment, it's not a matter of it being impossible. Bitmaps in memory are different from files on disk. As the name suggests, FileInfo is for files. What kind of information are you looking for in your bitmap?

Comment: @nightWatcher It depends on what the facebook sdk requires.  If it needs a file then you'll have to create a file.  If it can accept a `Stream` then you can provide the data without an intermediate file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until it's been saved as a file, what exactly do you expect to get out of a `FileInfo` about it?  [Every property of that class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) directly relates to the file system properties of a file.  (Except arguably `.Length`, but you should be able to get that from whatever your data stream is without having to round-trip to the file system and create unnecessary I/O.)

To directly answer your question, yes, you'll need to have a file on the file system in order to create an instance of `FileInfo` to get its file system properties.  But I suspect there might be a deeper concern with which I can help depending on the actual needs of what you're trying to do.  Taking a step back, *why* specifically do you need a `FileInfo` object in this case?

Comment: Facebook SDK comes with the function for photo upload to the wall and it requires the fileinfo object, i guess ill have to save it to the disk first

Comment: @nightWatcher: It seems silly that they would require a file in order to transfer something across HTTP (I guess I'm _assuming_ it's over HTTP), which inherently doesn't know or care about files.  Where in the SDK is this method?  I don't know the SDK, but can browse the code and take a look.  (I'm assuming you're using this: http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/, correct?)

Comment: yes i am using SDK from codeplex , Iam using this function facebookService1.Photos.Upload(message,captio,fileinfo obj);
There is another method 
facebookService1.Stream.Publish(text, attachment, actionlink,target_id, uid)
But i am not yet able to figure it out,i have been searching for ant documentation on this function.

Comment: @nightWatcher: Maybe I'm just not seeing it, but I can't find an `Upload()` method in the SDK.  Where specifically is it?

Comment: I followed what you said:) fetching after storing it to hard disk worked for me thanks